# Animate CC. Movieclip проигрывается только 1 раз

Tags: animate, html5-canvas

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема с Animate CC. Я работают с HTML5 Canvas. Почему-то некоторые movieclip-ы перестали быть зацикленными. То есть играют только один раз. FLA файл с примером по ссылке:

[Не зациклен (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T_ogKZYrRfR-1YoGS6KOsUNqG2iWUFFN)

И еще пример с файлом где мувиклип зациклен нормально:

[Зациклен (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aYLYK6fH9kUyZ1-6AE93xWY0fBeO7UWL)

UPDATE1:
Когда я публикую проект и смотрю код сгенерированого js файла, то вижу строки добавления мувиклипа в библиотеку:

```
(lib.arrows = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
if (loop == null) { loop = false; } this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});
```

Я понимаю, что вот эта часть не даёт зациклить мувиклип:

```
if (loop == null) { loop = false; }
```

Но я не понимаю почему AnimateCC её добавляет, ведь 2 дня назад такой проблемы не было. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ. Когда я публикую проект, находясь **внутри мувиклипа** (без галочки "Loop timeline") - **он не зацикливается**. Но когда я, находясь на самом верхнем уровне (Scene), публикую проект (без галочки "Loop timeline") - всё в порядке, мувиклип зациклен. Не знаю, может так и должно быть. Прокомментируйте пожалуйста.

**Update**

Если вы всё еще не поняли что делать и ваши мувиклипы не зациклены, делаем вот что. Заходим в настройки проекта и ставим галочку "Loop timeline" (если она не стоит). Теперь заходим внутрь мувиклипа который надо зациклить и публикуем проект (SHIFT+ALT+F12 или ваше сочетание клавиш для публикации). Готово! Теперь мувиклип должен зациклиться.